# Copying a specfic line within a cell into another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple lines within a cell, all with line breaks.

e.g.

```
Name: a

Age: 1

University: 1

Degree: 3

Year: 3
```

I am looking to extract (in this example) the University infomation that is contained within the cell and copy it into another cell in another column.

There are about 1000 records in my document so to copy and paste by hand will be time consuming.

Any help will be appreciated

Cheers

Joe

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your question? Could you leave a comment or accept the answer of your choice?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an Excel formula.

Assuming your data is in column A, and you want the extraction in column B, and assuming you put a title in row 1, you could do as in the following image:

[image: ![enter image description here]

(Note that I have a semi-colon in the formula as list separator, use comma instead)

The formula in `B2` is:

```
=MID($A2, FIND(B$1, $A2) + LEN(B$1), 
          FIND(CHAR(10), $A2 & CHAR(10), FIND(B$1, $A2)) - FIND(B$1, $A2) - LEN(B$1))
```

The formula has some duplication; here are some of the parts explained:

- `FIND(B$1, $A2)` returns the position of the title in the text
- `FIND(B$1, $A2) + LEN(B$1)` returns the position of what follows that title in the text
- `FIND(CHAR(10), $A2 & CHAR(10), FIND(B$1, $A2))` returns the position of a newline character following the title, making sure that if none is present, a position beyond the string length is returned

As long as you put the column titles to whatever sub-string you are looking for, you can copy/drag the same formula to other columns and rows.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a **single** break between each line, then in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))
```

[image]

This assumes that:

- the university line is the *third* line
- you want the entire line

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an answer even though you haven't provided what attempts you've made so far, which is how questions on this site usually work...but today I'm feeling generous :)

Use a combination of `MID` and `FIND` formulas, like the following:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("University",A1),FIND("Degree",A1)-FIND("University",A1)-2)
```

I put your example text in Cell A1 for my test, and it returned `University: 1`.  This however will only work if `University` is always followed by `Degree` in the text strings.

The other method would be to replace the last part of your `MID` statement (the part asking for length to return) with the exact number of characters to return, which in this case would be 13, like the following:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("University",A1),13)
```

This assumes that the integer associated with `University` is always 1 character in length.

Either way, a combination of the above two formulas should get you what you need.  VBA should not be necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Lines in a cell value are separated by the line feed character `vbLf`, so to extract the information out of the cell value you can use String-Functions `Mid(...)` and `InStr(...)`:

```
Dim cellValue as String
Dim extracedValue as String
Dim keyWord as String
Dim posStart as Integer, posEnd as Integer

extractedValue = "" ' Not necessary, but I prefer initialized variables
cellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value ' Put your cell here
keyWord = "University" ' Put your keyword here

posStart = InStr(1, cellValue, keyWord) ' Find keyword in the string
If (posStart > 0) Then
    posEnd = InStr(posStart, cellValue, vbLf) ' Find next line feed after the keyword
    If (posEnd > 0) Then
        extractedValue = Mid(cellValue, posStart, posEnd - posStart) ' Extract the value
    End If
End If
```

I haven't tested the code, but you should get the idea.